# NFS mounts don't work for some clients

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

I'm running an NFS server on Debian 11 (Bookworm)
I'd installed the package nfs-kernel-server and have the following in my /etc/exports

```
/mnt/2TB        192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(rw,anongid=1000,anonuid=1000,async,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash)
/mnt/2TB/weewx  192.168.1.182(insecure,rw,all_squash,anonuid=997,insecure,anongid=33,async)
/mnt/2TB/octoprint      192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(anongid=1000,all_squash,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,rw,async)
/mnt/2TB/media  192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0(anongid=996,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash,async,rw,anonuid=1001)
```

For some reason, some of my clients can access these NFS shares without any problem... specifically a Windows 10 PC, and Kodi running on a Google Chromecast.... yet other clients, specifically my raspberry pi devices, cannot access these NFS shares.    They appear to mount, but I cannot access the directories at all, not even as root.

sudo showmount -a on the server shows the clients are in fact connected.

```
john@thindebian:~$ sudo showmount -a
All mount points on thindebian:
192.168.1.150:/mnt/2TB
192.168.1.3:/mnt/2TB
192.168.1.67:/mnt/2TB
192.168.1.67:/mnt/2TB/media
192.168.1.67:/mnt/2TB/octoprint
192.168.1.67:/mnt/2TB/weewx
192.168.1.76:/mnt/2TB
```

192.168.1.67 is my Google Chromecast
192.168.1.150 and 192.168.1.3 are my raspberry pis
192.168.1.76 is my windows 10 pc

the mount command on the raspberry pi shows the share is in fact mounted

```
192.168.1.2:/mnt/2TB on /mnt/2TB type nfs (rw,noatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,soft,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.1.2,mountvers=3,mountport=43215,mountproto=tcp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.2)
```

The file permissions for the shared directory are

```
drwsrwsrwx 1 nobody nogroup 2.6K Dec  2 00:04 2TB
```

Oddly enough.... this was all working fine a month ago and just stopped working on the raspberry pi devices.

I'm at a loss as to where to go from here.  Perhaps I'm just missing something obvious, I don't know.... Can anyone offer any suggestions/assistance?

Comment: Dont know if it might point to the problem, but when it was working fine, i wasnt using the insecure parameter, but then one day nothing could connect...but adding that insecure parameter now at least lets the chromecast/kodi and windows pc connect.

Comment: When you mount on your Raspberry client what do you get by using `sudo mount -vt nfs` (`-v` for verbose mode)?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/nfs.conf` file for `udp=n`.

Re-enabling it should allow your UDP based clients to connect.

[Bookworm Bug - NFS UDP disabled by default](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1050840)

Comment: I don't have nor want any udp clients connecting.   I'm specifying proto=tcp in the fstab file